# How to solve this first order non-linear (quadratic) inhomogenous ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

How can I find a solution to the following first order nonlinear (quadratic) ODE?

$$ h(t)=a\dot h(t)\sqrt{b-c \dot h(t)^2} $$

I am solving a physics problem, namely, finding the time it takes for a cylinder to sink in water, and need to find the function $h$.

The water that the cylinder is in can be considered as nonviscous. Therefore I used conservation of energy and the continuity equation to obtain this equation. I think that my physical reasoning is correct although some approximations I made might not be reasonable. I want to verify this by solving this equation and evaluating the time.

In case this raises concerns, I am not interested in obtaining a solution by the work of others without own contribution, I want to know if this ODE is solvable analytically and if so, which methods I should use / learn to solve it. Regarding my knowledge on DEs, aside from special cases like using characteristic polynomials or the harmonic oscillator, I only know separation of variables and variation of constants for inhomogeneous first order linear ODEs.

Comment: You should show us some amount of work you have done to solve the problem. If you really have no idea how to start, then it might be a good idea to provide context for what the original physics problem looked like, and what you understand about the problem.

Comment: The problem is to find the time it takes for a cylinder to sink in water. I substituted the physical constants with a, b, c.

Comment: The water that the cylinder is in can be considered as nonviscous. Therefore I used conservation of energy and the continuity equation to obtain this equation. I think that my physical reasoning is correct although some approximations I made might not be reasonable. I want to verify this by solving this equation and evaluating the time. But yes, @C-RAM, I do not know how to solve this ODE or any useful literature to do so.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The square comes from the kinetic energy. I think it is quadratic because \dot h is multiplied with the square root of \dot h^2.

Comment: Do you really need to take the SQRT?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am taking the SQRT because I need to substitute the velocity into the continuity equation in which the velocity is only linear. However from the energy conservation I obtain v^2.

Comment: Why don't you show your derivation?  You don't pay extra tax if you write a longer question. Please use MathJax whenever possible. If you have diagrams, you can photograph them and upload the photos.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I can upload my derivation. It will take me some time but this is no problem at all. However, if this equation cannot be solved analytically in the first place, I know that I need to check my calculations.

Comment: In case this raises concerns, I am not interested in obtaining a solution by the work of others without own contribution, I want to know if this ODE is solvable analytically and if so, which methods I should use / learn to solve it. Regarding my knowledge on DEs, aside from special cases like using characteristic polynomials or the harmonic oscillator, I only know separation of variables and variation of constants for inhomogeneous first order linear ODEs.

Comment: @EliasK. The question should be self-contained. Comments are ephemeral.  The comment section is not the place to provide details.  Again, you don't pay extra tax if you write a longer question.

Comment: Amusingly, recasting the equation with $h$ as the independent variable allows some progress. Let $t=t(h)$ so that $h'(t)=1/t'(h)$. Then square the equation and solve for $(t')^2$. Then your equation is reduced to (the various branches of) $\frac{dt}{dh}=f(h)$, so you 'just' need to integrate. To these integrals, a CAS gives horrible but exact solutions in terms of $\coth^{-1}(\dots)$

Comment: Square your equation, to get a quadratic in $h'(t)^2$. Solve it, take the square root, and you will get $h'(t)$ in terms of $h(t),\ a,\ b,\ c$